# Rename List with powershell SP2013

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, rename

I know this is a really simple task and I have done it a thousand times and it worked every time, but I cannot rename a list via powershell anymore.

```
$List = $web.Lists["mylist"]
$List.Title = "newtitle"
$List.Update()
```

When I check the Title in a seperate powershell window the name is correct. 
Also if I check the List in SharePoint Manager2013 the Title is the new one.

But in the GUI it stays the same. I tried reloading the page and clearing the cache and everything, but it does not change.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Are you using minimal download strategy on the site? It's always activated on new sites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be a language / culture issue. Try this script instead. It renames the list for all in SPWeb supported cultures.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite

ForEach($culture in $web.SupportedUICultures)
{
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=$culture;
    $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("mylist") 
    $list.Title = "newtitle";
    $list.Update();
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)